# How can I log originating IP addresses under Pantheon?

Tags: nginx, logging, pantheon

We have a Drupal site running under Pantheon.  We would like to keep a log similar to Apache's access.log showing the REQUEST_URI of each page hit, along with the originating IP address.  This is so that if we observe someone abusing the site, we can look back through the log and get the IP address of the abuser.  I would think just about every Pantheon client would want this ability, which is why I'm surprised that it seems to be so difficult.  I hope I'm just missing something obvious.  I've investigated two possible avenues:

(1) Use the nginx-access.log file.  This has all the information I need, except that the IP address stored is an internal Pantheon IP address such as 10.223.177.45, instead of the originating IP address.  I asked Pantheon support about getting the originating IP address stored in nginx-access.log, and got this response:

> You are asking us to change the way log files are stored, that is not
>   going to happen. The settings are set universally across our entire
>   platform. As I stated the 10.223.177.45 is an *internal* IP address
>   from Pantheon.
>
> There is not a way to accomplish this.

I have trouble believing there is "not a way to accomplish this", since the originating IP address is made available via PHP as `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`.  Clearly, they have the information, but for some reason don't want to store it in nginx-access.log.

(2) Build our own log file from PHP, storing `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` and `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`.  We already have a bunch of custom code in sites/default/settings.php, and we could add something that uses `file_put_contents` to add a line to a log file.  Maybe something like this:

```html
<?php file_put_contents('sites/default/files/private/access.log', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . ' ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] . ' ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "\n", FILE_APPEND); ?>
```

But then we'd have to rotate that log file when it got full.  I guess we can do that...it's just a maintenance bother.

Has any other Pantheon client encountered this issue before, and found a simpler solution?

Answer (score 0):

Solution 2 with a simple rule to delete old log files on cron should be good enough.

I am not a pantheon user but its possible to do this using modules as well if thats 'simpler'
http://drupalnotes.com/post/64855594431/the-search-for-the-ideal-drupal-7-statistics